# Where is the barrier between using uint256 and bytes32?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Since both uint256 and bytes32 space are 2^256, what are the general practices for prioritizing using one over the other? why is bytes32 more expensive to execute gaswise than uint256?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`uint256` is generally used for:

- Addresses
- Numbers
- Account balances
- Doing math like `+` `-` `*` `/` or `**`

`bytes32` is generally used for:

- Small strings of no more than 32 characters
- Hashes (the `sha3(..)` functions returns a `bytes32`)
- Raw data (of whatever meaning you like)
- Situations where you need to read a specific byte like `a[4]`

The comparison operators work for both `uint256` and `bytes32`:

`<=` `<` `>=` `>` `==` `!=`

Also, the bitwise operators work for both `uint256` and `bytes32`:

`&` `|` `^` `~` `<<` `>>`

Comment: Thanks Jesse, can you explain why bytes32 is more expensive than uint256 of same size?

Comment: @ABGhostCoder I do not know. I'm trying to analyze the bytecode produced by the Solidity compiler. It seems that the compiler uses 3 extra instructions to load a `bytes32` function parameter, compared to a `uint256`. Also, it uses 11 extra instructions to return a `bytes32`. With optimizations turned on, these differences disappear completely. I would assume that as the optimizer is improved more and more, `bytes32` should eventually be equally expensive as `uint256`.